# Capture keys sent to a specific application in Linux

Tags: python, c, linux, linux-kernel, keylogger

Ideally, I would like to capture the keys sent to a specific program (and *only* to that program)  e.g. Dwarf Fortress.  [and later send keystrokes to only that program - which is easier to do]

A workaround would be to run the application in Docker or a VM and capture all keystrokes with something like `[logkeys][1]` but it would be more preferable to have a wrapper or some other approach for the specific application.

I am looking to structure a solution to this problem.
Should I be using device drivers? (But how would I limit it to only that application?) or is there something specific I should be aware of e.g. Python / C already has that ... why not just use `keytrace` etc?

EDIT: Upon further reflection, this seems like something being handled at the window manager level - perhaps that could be an approach.

Comment: This received a downvote - I'd be curious to know why - 
a) the voter thought it was trivial - if so, who passes up a 100 bounty?  b) it's not generally of interest / too specific - given that there are 50K keylogging questions - it seems that logging to one program would be of great interest

Answer (score 0):

If your application creates an X11 window, or runs inside an X11 window (*e.g.* in a terminal emulator), you can capture the X11 events which target that specific window.

With the application running, use `xwininfo` to determine the window’s identifier: run `xwininfo`, click on the target window, and look for

```
xwininfo: Window id: ...
```

in the output.

Then run `xev`, intercepting events sent to the target window:

```
xev -id ... -event keyboard
```

replacing `...` with the window id determined above.

The result is rather verbose, but it can be post-processed:

```
KeyPress event, serial 18, synthetic NO, window 0x4000003,
    root 0x187, subw 0x0, time 141181493, (369,-10), root:(369,54),
    state 0x0, keycode 116 (keysym 0xff54, Down), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 21, synthetic NO, window 0x4000003,
    root 0x187, subw 0x0, time 141181653, (369,-10), root:(369,54),
    state 0x0, keycode 116 (keysym 0xff54, Down), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 21, synthetic NO, window 0x4000003,
    root 0x187, subw 0x0, time 141182188, (369,-10), root:(369,54),
    state 0x0, keycode 116 (keysym 0xff54, Down), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

This doesn’t work for all X11 applications, but it does work with Dwarf Fortress.

Under X11 the window manager doesn’t process keyboard input for individual applications.